# Cannot make a Rectangle to display with Unity + Oculus Rift

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I'm trying to display a simple rectangle right in front of my OVRPlayerController's camera but it seems to be impossible.
I think it might have something to do with the fact that Rect is 2D and my environment is 3D. Does that make sense?

The code is the following (I have ommited the unnecessary stuff):

```
static  int MAX_MENU_OPTIONS = 3;
public  GameObject Menu;
private bool showMenu = false;
private float menuIndex = 0;
private bool hasPressedDirectionalPad = false;
public  Transform[] buttons = new Transform[MAX_MENU_OPTIONS];
private static Texture2D staticRectTexture;
private static GUIStyle staticRectStyle;



bool DpadIsPressed() {
    if (!hasPressedDirectionalPad && Input.GetAxis("DpadY") != 0 && hasPressedDirectionalPad == false){
        menuIndex += Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("DpadY")) * (-1);
        if (menuIndex < 0) menuIndex = 0;
        else if (menuIndex > MAX_MENU_OPTIONS-1) menuIndex = MAX_MENU_OPTIONS-1;
        hasPressedDirectionalPad = true;
    }
    if(Input.GetAxis("DpadY") == 0){
        hasPressedDirectionalPad = false;
    }
    return hasPressedDirectionalPad;
}

void Start() {
    Menu.SetActive(false);
    staticRectTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
    staticRectStyle = new GUIStyle();
}

void Update() {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("A")) {
        DoAction ();
        print ("A key was pressed");
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Options")) {
        showMenu = !showMenu;
        if (showMenu) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            menuIndex = 0;
            Menu.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
            Menu.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        } else
            Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
    if (DpadIsPressed ()) {

        print ("Dpad key was pressed and menuIndex = " + menuIndex);
    }
    if (showMenu) {
        Menu.SetActive (true);
    }
    if (!showMenu) {
        Menu.SetActive (false);
    }

}

void OnGUI() {
    if (showMenu) {
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.2f);
        Vector3 posSelectRectangle = buttons[(int)menuIndex].transform.position + offset;
        Rect selectionRectangle = new Rect(posSelectRectangle.x - (float)177/2,
                                           posSelectRectangle.y - (float)43/2,
                                           177.0f, 43.0f);
        GUIDrawRect(selectionRectangle, new Color(255.0f, 0, 0));
    }
}


void DoAction () {
    if (menuIndex == 0)
        Salir ();
    /*else if (menuIndex == 1)
        Guardar ();*/
    else if (menuIndex == 2)
        Salir ();
}

public static void GUIDrawRect(Rect position, Color color ) {
    staticRectTexture.SetPixel( 0, 0, color );
    staticRectTexture.Apply();

    staticRectStyle.normal.background = staticRectTexture;
    GUI.Box( position, GUIContent.none, staticRectStyle );
}
```

The functions are visited, but the rectangle doesn't show up. Do you see the mistake? Maybe it has something to do with the Oculus Rift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnGUI and Screen-space Canvas are not supported in VR mode. This is because there is no way to handle stereoscopic rendering. (Note: They will render to the duplicate display on the user's PC though).

If you want to render in front of the user's camera (like a HUD), you can:

**Use a Canvas:**

Create a canvas, then add your UI, and set the canvas in world-space. Parent the canvas to the VR Camera game object, and scale it down (it defaults to very very big) and rotate it so it faces the camera.

**Or, Use 3D:**

Create a 3d Object (Plane, Cube, Quad, whatever!) and parent it to your VR Camera. You can use standard 3d techniques to update it's texture or render texture.